# Meaning of "feels begin and end the tears" in Browning's Childe Roland

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From [Childe Roland](http://www.bartleby.com/246/654.html):

> As when a sick man very near to death
>     Seems dead indeed, and **feels begin and end
>
>     The tears** and takes the farewell of each friend,
>   And hears one bid the other go, draw breath
>   Freelier outside, (“since all is o’er,” he saith,
>     “And the blow fallen no grieving can amend;”)

What is the meaning of this phrase? Does it mean that he somehow feels that the mourners begin crying, and then stop crying?

Comment: It's an inversion: he feels the tears begin and end. Each friend weeps while taking leave of the dying man, but stops weeping upon leaving the room. "And still the man hears all, and only craves / He may not shame such tender love and stay."

Comment: @StoneyB - thank you! Please feel free to post your comments as answers right away. If you're too shy of getting a surfeit of points, you could post them in community wiki form. ^_^

Comment: A pretty good Elizabethan knock-off.

Comment: @TRomano - what is "knock-off"? Imitation?

Comment: imitation or emulation, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an inversion: he feels the tears begin and end. Each friend weeps while taking leave of the dying man, but stops weeping upon leaving the room. "And still the man hears all, and only craves / He may not shame such tender love and stay."

(Kudos to StoneyB)